# while trying to create django-admin startproject :No module name django-admin

Tags: python, django, windows

while trying to create project using django i installed globally, it says module not found.everything was working fine before i Tried to install another version python, even going back to the previous version didnt help and also tried to uninstall every pip package and reinstall again. i have set path and django is in the script folder as mentioned in the path. virtualenvironment is working fine and i can actually install django in virtual environment but not using the locally installed django.

```
D:\ALL_PROJECTS>python -m django-admin startproject example
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe: No module named django-admin
```

Comment: you have to activate virtual environment and install django

Comment: Hey, don't use python -m . Command is -   django-admin startproject sanalo

Comment: `django-admin` is an executable that you run directly from the CLI. It's not a Python program.

Comment: then i get this error :: Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'

Comment: activating  virtual environmentworks but i want to create project using the django installed in the python path folder

Comment: Are you using windows ? Do you need step by step to create venv and create project?

Comment: i did create a virtualenvironment and installed django there and everything works fine...all i am asking is why cant i create django project using the django-admin that i installed globally and cannot access that django-admin....virtual env is fine and all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing a similar problem. what I did was deleted the django-admin files from local user and global python sites package folder, and then uninstall the django version, after that reinstalling the django version of my choice worked charm for me.

if you are confused with where the location of django-admin is then you can look by typing cmd.

`where django-admin`

in windows.